When building a vs2022 project in github/devops that includes architecture dependency graphs, the build fails MSB4226
I have a project working with builds in both github and devops. I recently added an architecture dependency diagram per https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/devopsserver/livedependencyvalidation/
This builds fine locally, and correctly enforces dependencies.
However, I get failures in build in both devops and github.
Interestingly, even with the error, if there are dependency errors, they seem to be correctly identified and warned.
But in the case where there are no dependency errors, the build errors out anyway.
Both devops and github give the same error (see bottom)
I have the  Microsoft.DependencyValidation.Analyzers nuget in the solution/projects.
I have seen several other posts various places with the same underlying problem, but in earlier versions of VS.
In that the one linked, the answer by @duncanp says that the  ModelingProject.targets is a legacy method, and can be removed if you aren't using 2015. But the lines referenced are not in my project/solution files right now, so I can't remove them as suggested. Since the targets arent in my solution to begin with, I am unsure what is causing this error to happen (perhaps they are implicitly included?)
Visual Studio 2017 dependency validation project on build server
DependencyValidation\DependencyValidation.modelproj(66,11): Error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
devops pipeline (trimmed to the relevant build steps
):
parameters:
- name: solution
  default: '**/*.sln'
- name: buildPlatform
  default: 'Any CPU'
- name: buildConfiguration
  default: 'Release'

# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
  branches:
    include: 
      - master
#  paths:
#    include: 
#      - 'WIGOV.Applications.Dashboard/**'

pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '${{ parameters.solution }}'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '${{ parameters.buildPlatform }}'
    configuration: '${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x86'

github pipeline (ive also tried with windows-latest instead of ubuntu):
# This workflow will build a .NET project
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-net

name: .NET

on:

  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
      with:
        dotnet-version: 8.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
    env:
      ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME: "${{ secrets.DSDWI_ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }}"
      ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.DSDWI_ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD }}"


What is the Visual Studio version on your local machine? Can you share some details about the azure pipeline or github build definition?

If it helps, my installation of VS2022 Community has the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\ArchitectureTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets" file and the VS Installer shows that I have the optional  "Modeling SDK" installed.

@KevinLu-MSFT Locally im using 2022.  I appended the build defs to the main text

@JonathanDodds that makes sense, but I don't think I can tell devops or github to install those packages, unless there is something I can put into the build def that controls that

Looks like this is your problem: Edition support for architecture and modeling tools

@JasonCoyne Are you using Microsoft hosted agents? Have you looked up the VM image description to see what software (and edition) is provided in the image?

@JasonCoyne The cause of the issue is that The Visual Studio component: Dependency Validation(contains Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets) is not pre-installed on all Microsoft-hosted agents. I have shared the steps in the answer to share the steps to install the component in MS hosted agent. You can also consider using self-hosted agent to run the pipeline, it will reduce the rum time of the pipeline.

From your YAML sample, you are using Microsoft-Hosted Agents in Azure Pipeline.
Refer to this doc about the pre-installed components of Visual Studio in Microsoft-hosted agents.
The Visual Studio component: Dependency Validation(contains Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamArchitect.ModelingProject.targets) is not pre-installed on all Microsoft-hosted agents.
This is the cause of the issue.
To solve this issue, we need to add additional script to install the component: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.ArchitectureTools.Managed in Visual Studio on Microsoft-hosted agents.
Refer to the doc about install component of Visual Studio: Use command-line parameters to install, update, and manage Visual Studio
In Azure Pipeline, you can use the following script to achieve it.
For example:
steps:
- powershell: |
      $source = "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_enterprise.exe"
      $destination = "$(build.sourcesdirectory)\vs_enterprise.exe"
      $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
      $cookie = "oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
      $client.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, $cookie) 
      $client.downloadFile($source, $destination)
  displayName: 'Download vs.exe'

- script: 'vs_enterprise.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.ArchitectureTools.Managed'
  displayName: 'Install ArchitectureTools'

- script: ls
  workingDirectory: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\ArchitectureTools'
  displayName: 'check install result'

Result:

Then you can run the VSbuild task to build your project.
But the installation process takes about 6 minutes, which will increase the running time of the Pipeline.
You can also consider using Self-hosted Agent in Azure Pipeline.
In this case, it will directly use the local environment to compile your project without installing the Visual Studio component.

This is very helpful, I will try it shortly.  Do you have any help on the github side? (due to conflicting corporate and client requirements, we have to use both)

@JasonCoyne I am not so familiar with GitHub action. But I think you can add the similar steps to GitHub to install the vs component, because github and azure pipeline are using same agent image

@JasonCoyne Is there any update about this ticket? May I know if the answer can work for you in Azure Pipleine?

It appears to work correctly in devops, though it does slow down the process significantly.  If you have the connections, I would suggest having that package added into the images.
Unfortunately I cant merge that branch until I figure out the equivalent steps in github, but its progress!

@JasonCoyne https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues You can add your requirement in this site. The image used by azure pipeline and github action will collect feedback through this site
